# font awesome icon loading "shifted" on an angle

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Anybody had this problem? For unknown to me reason icons appear "on angle".

```
<i class="fas fa-plane"></i>

i.fas.fa-plane {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
font-size: 4rem;
}
```

Tried to use `Power Transforms` , they don`t work.

**This is how the icon is suppose to be positioned:**

[image]

**This how it loads like :**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the icon is supposed to appear flying at an angle.
https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/plane

If you want to shift it yourself without Power Transforms, try:
`<div style="-ms-transform: rotate(45deg);transform: rotate(45deg);"><i class="fas fa-plane"></i></div>`

Comment: thing is, this one is on angle in v4.7, but straight in v5. i think i know what the problem might be.... i was using bootstrap link when i was declaring `<link>` `stylesheet`, and it is v4.7. But some of the icons where v5 - which may be the reason why some of the icons where loading deformed.....

Answer (score 0):

The problem was probably in different versions of the icons i was using, and different version declared in the head link (i was using bootstrap v4.x). That probably was causing conflict when i tried to use icons v5 - and they were appearing deformed.

Ps. This particular example above has different angles of the font in different versions.

I've downloaded Font Awesome on my PC and everything running sweet now. 
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself